# TabControl avoid changing to another tab

Tags: tabcontrol, selectedindexchanged

I have a tab control with 2 tabs.. When the user clicks on the second tab, it does some validation and then if that validation returns false, the user gets a message indicating to go back. Now, here's my problem, it changes tabs anyways with the code below:
Although the user doesn't see the tab 2, it is showing as changed.

```
   private void tabprincipal_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!saved_plan)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to save a plan first.");
                return;
            }
```

How can I avoid this behavior? I want to display the message and the user to remain in the first tab

I think I'm looking for an event prior to the selectedindexchanged to detect that the user clicked tab2 and then don't let him move..

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way using the Deselecting method of the TabControl

```
private void tabprincipal_Deselecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!saved_plan)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to save a plan first");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```